# How to ask for an item that is behind the shop window?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, conversation

You are just passing by a shop and an item catches your eye. You want to ask the shopkeeper about that item. What do you say? is "in the window" an appropriate phrase for that?

> Could you show me the jacket in the window?

Comment: Yes. Exactly right.

Comment: "How much is that doggy in the window?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly correct.

What might be confusing for a non-native English speaker is that if you take the question literally, it could be interpreted as:

> Could you show me the jacket that's *embedded in the window's pane of glass*.

Of course, the jacket isn't, literally, inside the window itself. You're quite right to think that it's *behind* the window. (If you're standing on the street; otherwise, if you're in the shop, it's *in front of* the window.)

When we say *window* in this context, what we really mean is:

> Could you show me the jacket that's *part of the window display*?